# Defining path on the prime spectrum

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

If $p$ and $q $ are two prime ideals of a commutative ring $R $ such that $p \subseteq q$, then we can easily define a continuous function (a path) $f$ from the unit interval $ [0,1]$ to the prime spectrum $ Spec (R)$, with the Zariski topology, such that $f (0)=p$  and $f (1)=q$. (Also, in general, if there exists a zigzag of specializations of prime ideals between  $p $ and $q $, then we can find a path between $p $ and $q $).  Now if there exists no zigzag of specializations of prime ideals between  $p $ and $q $, I am looking for some conditions (on $p $ and $q$) under which there exists a path between $ p$ and $q $.

Comment: The components (in the partial-order sense, i.e., equivalence classes  of the "exists a zigzag" relation) of the partial order of prime ideals are open and closed in the Zariski topology, so the image of a continuous map from $[0,1]$ (or from any connected space) cannot meet more than one of them.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's not quite right. If $V$ is a valuation ring of infinite rank, you can have the situation $\mathrm{Spec}(V)=\{0,1,\ldots,\infty\}$ with the topology for which the open sets are all $\{n,n+1,\ldots,\infty\}$. In that case there is a map $[0,1]\to \mathrm{Spec}(V)$ connecting $0$ to $\infty$: On $[0,1/2]$, map to $0$, on $(1/2,3/4]$ map to $1$, on $(3/4,7/8]$ map to $2$ etc., finally mapping $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: There is a rich theory of homotopy types of finite non-Hausdorff spaces: see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+topological+space for some references.  Similar phenomena will appear if you study homotopy types of Zariski spectra of rings.

Comment: @PeterScholze I don't (yet) understand your comment. In your example, isn't the partial order of prime ideals just a linear order, so every two ideals are joined by a zigzag (a single zig or a single zag)?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oops, I'm sorry, you are of course right. But can you not build a version of this example that includes specializations back and forth? I think this ought to be a spectral space, still.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/q/379341/160416, which has an answer in comments